# How to include classpath jars into a jar in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I am developing a desktop application using swingx, spring and using ant to build them. This is my first project in ant. 
How can add classpath jars to the executable jar build by ant? I have swingx, spring jar into my classpath. This my target for jar:

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
    <jar destfile="build/jar/MainClass.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MainClass" />
        </manifest>         
    </jar>
</target>
```

Edit:

```
<project name="Number">
    <description>
            description
    </description>

    <property name="lib" value="lib" />
    <property name="src" value="src" />
    <property name="build" value="build" />
    <property name="classes" value="classes" />
    <property name="jar" value="jar"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build}" />
    </target>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${build}/${classes}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/${classes}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="clean, compile">
        <mkdir dir="${build}/${jar}" />
        <jar destfile="build/jar/Number.jar" basedir="${build}/${classes}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MainClass" />
            </manifest>
            <fileset file="test.txt">
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="${build}/${jar}/MainClass.jar" fork="true" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add them with the following code:

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
        <classpath>
               <fileset dir="${lib}">
                  <include name="**/*.jar" />
               </fileset>
         </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </jar>

</target>
```

This would include all *.jar files which are under the  **${lib}** folder.

But this code should be in an ant **compile** target. Because before generating the jar bundle you need to compile it. And therefore you need the swingx, spring jars.

Comment: Where to put it inside <jar destfile=""/> node?

Comment: I gave you now the code with a compile target together. Important is that the jar target is depending on the compile and you handle there the class path with the jars. Hope now it's clear :). Check this tutorial for the basic ant structure: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

Comment: I first read that tutorial and did it as shown in my edit. But the swingx jar is not added up into the Number.jar and that is why my code is not working, failed to launch.